# Vuex: Best way to handle list and detail data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am currently setting up a Headless CMS Blog with Nuxt.js/Vue.js. The main data types are **blogposts.** I want to setup a LIST and DETAIL View for the blogposts.

In TypeScript, I set the following interface for one Blogpost:

**blogposts.types.ts**

```
export interface Blogpost {
  id: number,
  enabled: boolean,
  headline: string,
  teaser: string,
  content: string
}
```

In my vuex store is structured like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
  allBlogposts: [],
  currentBlogpost: [],
});
```

When I load all the Blogposts(ListView), I use an async action to call all the blogposts from the API. In the Mutation, I use the interface, to structure the blogpost:

**blogposts.ts**

```
const api = 'http://localhost:1337/blogposts/';

export const actions = {
  async setBlogposts(state) {
    const allBlogposts = await axios.get(api);
    state.commit('setBlogposts', allBlogposts.data);
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  setBlogposts(state, allBlogposts) {
    const variants: Blogpost[] = [];

    // get each blogpost, normalize them and push it into an array.
    allBlogposts.forEach(blogpost => {
      const normalizedBlogpost: Blogpost = {
        id: blogpost.id,
        enabled: blogpost.Enabled,
        headline: blogpost.Headline_de,
        teaser: blogpost.Teaser_de,
        content: blogpost.Content_de
      };
      variants.push(normalizedBlogpost);
    });

    state.allBlogposts = variants;
  },
};
```

Now, what is the best way to handle the detail view of blogposts?

In my mind, there are two ways:

- consume the api `(/blogposts/1)`, fully decoupled from the code above
- get the object from the **allBlogposts** state.

Now, if the better way is, to get the object from the state: How could I implement this in TypeScript/JavaScript?

For the first way, I already implemented the following working code. But I feel like, having double API calls is not neccessary.

```
  // mutation
  setCurrentBlogpost(state, currentBlogpost) {
    // LANGUAGE DETECTION HERE !! //
    const normalizedBlogpost: Blogpost = {
      id: currentBlogpost.id,
      enabled: currentBlogpost.Enabled,
      headline: currentBlogpost.Headline_de,
      teaser: currentBlogpost.Teaser_de,
      content: currentBlogpost.Content_de
    };
    state.currentBlogpost = normalizedBlogpost;
  }

  // action
  async setCurrentBlogpost(state, blogpostId) {
    const currentBlogpost = await axios.get(api + blogpostId);
    state.commit('setCurrentBlogpost', currentBlogpost.data);
  }
```

Comment: The detail view i would decoupel it. I would fetch it an single blogpost with `fetch()` provided by nuxt

Comment: Does the detail view require any data that currently doesn't exist in `state.currentBlogpost`?  if so you'll need another API call. otherwise, just access the individual blog post using an array index.

Comment: are you showing them both on the same page? is this an SPA or SSR

Comment: @PirateApp There is a "list-view" which displays a Teaser of a blogpost and the headline. the detail-view also displays both of them, but more. It's a SPA .